# What's the Python equivalent to iterating over a defined table in Lua?

Tags: python, lua

I am very new to learning Python as I have just moved from Lua. One of my questions though, is how do I iterate over a table with a given set of different values? I have tried looking on other forums, but still do not understand and would like the easiest solution possible, as well explained.

For example, I have a table of numbers, and would like to iterate through that table, printing both the key and the element of the table. How would I do this in Lua?

This is what I mean when written in Lua:

```
local table = {1, 3, 5, 7;}

for i,v in pairs(table) do
    print(v)
end
```

Comment: firstly `local table` is not a valid name also dont know why theres a `;` at the end, and I think you want a list meaning you should use these `[]` brackets

Comment: @JosipJuros It's Lua given as an example of what OP wants to achieve, not Python

Comment: Can you please add the output for you code in the question?

Comment: Best to phrase the title as *"What's the Python equivalent to X in Lua?"*, and also tag it both [tag:python],[tag:lua]. That way, noone will misread your Lua code as being Python, also you'll probably get more Lua-aware responses. But please do skim the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) so you start learning the Python terms for things.

Comment: Also, in Python we pretty rarely need to use `enumerate()` to get the index for a list element, because we have list comprehensions and suchlike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this:

```py
table = [1, 3, 5, 7]  # create the list

for v in table:  # going through all elements of the list
    print(v)  # print the element
```

If you want to have the value and the index when going through the list, you can use `enumerate` like this:

```py
table = [1, 3, 5, 7]  # create the list

for i, v in enumerate(table):  # going through all elements of the list with their indexes
    print(i)  # print the element index
    print(v)  # print the element value
```

Comment: Oh ok, also, what if I'm trying to state the index too? Would I just include the "i" in the for loop?

Also, why doesn't it not close with 'end'? What's the alternative?

Comment: @vxsqi you can do `for i in range(len(table)):` and then you would access the elements as `table[i]`

Comment: I edited my answer in order to get the index

Comment: I see. What about 'end' in python? Does something like that exist?

Comment: The for block ends when you end the indented block.

Comment: The loop will end according to the indentation. Maybe [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) can help you to understand the for loops in python and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp) is about indentation.